# In has-a relation is it a good design, to access and alter the private members of contained class directly from the Parent class method

Tags: c++

Consider this example:

```
class Child
{
   private:
   string m_Name;

   public:
   string* GetNameAccess()
   {
      return &m_Name;
   }
};

class Parent
{
   private:
   Child m_Child;

   public:
   void DoSomething()
   {
      string *pChildName = m_Child.GetNameAccess();  // Is this the right thing to do?
      *pChildName = "NewName";
   }
};
```

In has-relation we know that Parent object owns the child object (i.e controls the lifetime of child).
So is Parent allowed to directly access the private members of child  and alter them ?

Comment: If I was to do this I wouldn't use a pointer. If you're going to provide public access to the variable through a function you may as well just make the variable public.

Comment: If it is allowed or not should be depending on what you want to achieve. There are many possibilities to achieve what you want to do. As I can say your way is one of the worst because you are using direct access with pointers. Either have a look at friend classes or use real getters and setters. The question is, why does the child not have a name at construction time and then you should ask yourself why someone should be allowed to change the name afterwards.

Comment: @RetiredNinja
What if string m_Name was actually string *p_mName; ?

Comment: If there was a raw pointer to a string in the class it would be worse than it is now.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX
I understand we can initialize child member through its constructor (And add setters and getters). But question is if Parent owns child object, does it not own the child members also?

Comment: You might consider letting the `Parent` *inherit* privately from `Child` and make the variable `protected`. Well, from point of view of class hierarchy names might be inverted ;)

Comment: @Avi that is not language dependent but design dependent as you see in your code. If the members are private only the class has access to it (without getters and setters). If they are protected also derived classes would have access and if it is public everyone has access. It does not depend on who creates the object or who "owns" it. There is no ownership concept or anything. The parent has a child object, not more not less. The parent is not an owner or anyhting else

Comment: If the class has a function that lets you access them, they're not really private, are they? You may as well just make  m_Name public, and stop beating about the bush

Comment: Pointers are not the first thing to go for in C++. The std::string class will do all the memory managment for you so you can make std::string a normal member (no pointer). And then you can return a reference to it e.g. `std::string&`

Comment: Okay makes sense now.
I think I am mixing composition definition with how classes and objects should behave.
For now I will think of ownership just as owning the lifetime of child object. Nothing else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although having a public function that returns a pointer to a private data member is *legal* in C++, it breaks the whole point of encapsulation. As mentioned in the comments, if you want to provide such 'direct' access to the data member, then just make it public.

But there are many good reasons why a data member *should* be private – such as offering some control(s) over what values are allowed or disallowed for that member. In such circumstances, you should provide *genuine* 'getter' and 'setter' functions to allow *controlled* access to that private member from outside the class. The 'getter' should not allow modification of the data (so returning a `const&` reference is generally appropriate) and the 'setter' should perform the required checks on the value it is given, before making a modification to the data.

Here is a very brief outline of how such a 'getter' and 'setter' may look for your example:

```cpp
#include <string>

class Child {
private:
    std::string m_Name;
public:
    const std::string& GetName() { // The "const" prevents modification with the getter
        return m_Name;
    }
    void SetName(const std::string& name) {
        // A real setter allows error checking ...
        if (name != "Attila the Hun") m_Name = name;
    }
};

class Parent {
private:
    Child m_Child;
public:
    void DoSomething() {
        std::string temp = m_Child.GetName();
        if (temp.empty()) temp = "New Name";
        else temp += " (Modified)";
        m_Child.SetName(temp);
    }
};
```

This short snippet demonstrates how you could prevent a parent naming their child, "Attila the Hun," which is perhaps a reasonable precaution for a setter function to implement.